# Как с помощью htaccess сократить url?

Tags: .htaccess

есть такой url https://napt.it/index.php?route=category/full/Work_and_training как в файле htaccess его сократить до такого url https://napt.it/Work_and_training

Comment: Что значит сократить? Redirect? Или чтоб при вводе короткого пути, работал как длинный?

Comment: это для настройки чпу, сейчас используется первый вариант, как сделать чтоб использовался второй, более красивый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так все виртуальные запросы будут отправляться на index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

А так с параметром **route=category/full/**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([0-9A-z_]+) index.php?route=category\/full\/$1
```